# How do you unlock new Smuggled Item locations?

Tags: hitman-2016

In Hitman (Reboot), how do you unlock new locations and costumes to go into a level with? It says you have to unlock them via challenges but doesn't specifically define each one.

Comment: Do the challenges and level up the experience on the level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for an enumerated list of challenges [this guide](http://hitman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Showstopper_Challenges_Guide) might be helpful.

A few example challenges from that list include:

Silent Assassin

> In order to complete this challenge, you need to complete the mission by killing only the targets, hiding all the bodies, and not getting spotted. Knocking out non-targets and hiding their bodies will not cause you to fail the mission.

Public Speaker

> To complete this assassination challenge, you'll need to drop a speaker on Viktor Novikov.

Speechless

> To complete this assassination challenge, you'll need to assassinate Viktor Novikov with a firearm while he's onstage.

Center of Attention

> To complete this assassination challenge, you'll need to drop a chandelier on Dalia Margolis during the auction.

Suit Only

> To complete this assassination challenge, you'll need to complete the mission without changing disguises: you need to only have used your suit.

Knockout Punch

> To complete this challenge, you need to assassinate Viktor Novikov with a poisoned cocktail.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is always best to include a summary of the contents of the link so the answer is still valid if the link goes down. Please edit your answer.